# How to export a huge table from BigQuery into a Google cloud bucket as one file

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-bucket

I am trying to export a huge table (2,000,000,000 rows, roughly 600GB in size) from BigQuery into a google bucket as a single file. All tools suggested in  [Google's Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#python) are limited in export size and will create multiple files.
Is there a pythonic way to do it without needing to hold the entire table in the memory?

Answer (score 1):

While perhaps there are other ways to make it as a script, the recommended solution is to merge the files using Google Storage `compose` action.

What you have to do is:

- export in CSV format
- this produces many files
- run the [compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composing-objects) action batched from 32 files until the final one, the big file is merged

All this can be combined in a cloud Workflow, there is a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/get-a-single-one-csv-file-with-bigquery-export-956d2a147886).

Comment: Thanks. I know how to create multiple file output and combine it. I am searching for a method to output it directly as one file.

Comment: What kind of method? There is no way to do that efficiently. You will need to slow down if you write a script as the APIs have limits, and it will take a lot of time to do it. The solution that we linked is just 25 lines of code to make it work - with cloud automation. The method that you need is the linked solution - cloud automation.